# Creating a new ObservableCollection using a collection of classes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, observablecollection

I have the following two classes:

```
 public class MyData
 {
     public MyData2 Data2 {get; set;}
 }

 public class MyData2
 {
     public string data {get; set;}
 }
```

I have an IList of MyData2, and I want to create a collection (`ObservableCollection` ideally, although I can easily convert) of MyData.  I feel it should be possible t do this using a lambda statement, but I can't seem to come up with the syntax; something like:

```
IList<MyData2> myData2 = GetData();
ObservableCollection<MyData> myData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>(Data2 = myData2??);
```

Is there a way to do this using labda / LINQ, or do I need to use a `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Enumerable.Select Method:

```
var myData = myData2.Select(data2 => new MyData() { Data2 = data2 });
var collection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>(myData);
```